# Digit recognition in Matlab using morphological operations

Tags: matlab

I have an image in png format of the digit ‘6’, I want to determine the position of the stem with respect to the blob using morphological operations. I have detected the blob of 6 using the code below. Now, I don't know how to detect the stem of the digit ‘6’. I tried using hough transform and edge detection algorithms but it didn't help.

Here is my code for detecting the blob:

```
img=imread('six.png');    
img=rgb2gray(img);    
figure,imshow(img);   
i1=im2bw(img);    
st=strel('square',20);    
imdilate(i1,st);    
figure,imshow(i1);    
i2=imfill(i1,'holes');    
figure,imshow(i2);    
i1=imsubtract(i2,i1);    
B = bwboundaries(i1);    
figure,imshow(i1)    
i2=i2-i1;    
figure,imshow(i2);    
text(10,10,strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(B))))    
hold on    

for k = 1:length(B)    
    boundary = B{k};    
    plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 0.2)

end

if eq(num2str(length(B)),'1')        
    h=msgbox('the number is 6');    
else    
    h=msgbox('unknown number');
end
```

Here's the original six image and my current output

[image: Input six]

[image: Output six]

Comment: Can you add a link to your six.png image so that I can see what your code does?

Comment: I can't post an image  becoz i am a new user to stack overflow and i need 10 reputation to post image.The above code finds the blob in the digit,as in case of 6 it is one.I am looking for a method that enables me to find that stem part is above the blob in digit 6

Comment: You can post a link and a higher rep user can add the image

Comment: Link for the image(six.png)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GdAgJfGp9iZ3ZLSUllMlpZdFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to morphological operations, you can simply find the pixels that are closest to the hole that you have already detected and remove them.

I start with the same morphological operations that you do, and add the extra step removing pixels within a distance threshold of the detected hole.

```
img=imread('six.png');    
img=im2bw(img);    
figure,imshow(img);   

filled_img=imfill(img,'holes');    
figure; imshow(filled_img);

filled_boundary= bwmorph(filled_img,'remove');
figure
imshow(filled_boundary)

hole = ~img & filled_img;
figure; imshow(hole);

hole_boundary = bwmorph(hole, 'remove');
figure; imshow(hole_boundary);

%Remove points on the boundary that are close to the hole
[hole_x, hole_y] = find(hole_boundary);
[fill_x, fill_y] = find(filled_boundary);
D = pdist2([hole_x, hole_y], [fill_x, fill_y]);
[distance, ~] = min(D, [], 1);

distance_threshold = 10;
top_edges = filled_boundary;
top_edges(fill_x(distance<distance_threshold), fill_y(distance<distance_threshold)) = 0;
figure; imshow(top_edges);
```

This is what my output image looks like

[image: Top of six]

Comment: I understood it, but how can i count the stems and how can i locate the position of stem,like in case of 6 it is above the blob and in 9 it is below the blob.

Comment: @SalmanBaqri I would suggest finding the centroid (center of gravity) of the stem and of the blob and comparing their coordinates.